# Local notifications firing instantly

Tags: android, notifications

Did you know that you cannot start a question with "Hi everyone,"?

Hi everyone,

the notification appears instantly at first start. Here is the code to setup the notification. It should appear daily between 9 and 10 am.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Log.v("TIMETIME", "schedule reminder: " + hour + ":" + minute);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
notificationIntent.putExtra(AlarmReceiver.NOTIFICATION, getNotification(context));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

On the other hand is the alarm broadcast receiver

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Dead simple but not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is with the calendar.
You call the set methods without moving a day foraward therefore most probably that you are trying to set an alarm for a time that has already passed.